# R, biocLite, error installing DESeq2

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I've been trying to install DESeq2 to do some analysis for a couple days now. R and biocLite are up to date, and I'm running into permission errors when I try to run

```
biocLite("DESeq2")
```

I receive mostly good messages, but at the end I get:

```
1: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘annotate’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘genefilter’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘geneplotter’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘DESeq2’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

I've tried editing permissions, running R through sudo, and adding my user to the staff group.

I'm at a loss, what else can I do to get this installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log, it seems that the problem originated from `XML` package. `XML` package fails to compile if `libxml2` library is not available. To install it on Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2 
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Then rerun the installation.

Comment: Is this the correct name for the library?

    $ sudo apt-get install libxm12
    Reading package lists... Done  
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package libxm12

Comment: libxml2, it's an L, not 1. You can just copy and paste from the answer

Comment: That makes a lot of sense for installing 'XML.' Thank you for your help @ahmohamed, I'm up and running.