# R, biocLite, libcurl not found

Tags: r, libcurl, miniconda

I'm running an error similar to [R, biocLite, error installing DESeq2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726649/r-bioclite-error-installing-deseq2) with the difference that I have the libxml2-dev and libcurl4-openssl-dev properly installed...

But I keep getting the same ERROR message in R:

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
```

Running on a Ubuntu 17.10 OS. Trying to install it in **miniconda** env.

Of note, libcurl4-openssl-dev properly installed.

Tried:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/cpat/miniconda3/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
```

Didn't help.

libcurl.pc files found in

```
/home/cpat/miniconda3/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
```

and

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
```

I really don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: You need to show either: a) what the pkg-config file looks like or b) what those environment variables mentioned in the error message look like.

Comment: Sorry, really not used to tall these PATH, configurations files. My $PATH looks like this: /home/cpat/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: Those comments would be more helpful as an [edit] to the question. That way you can preserve formats.

Comment: @42- Edited the question, as suggested. Hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: So is `pkg-config` in your path? What does `which pkg-config` return?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu too -- and it all works swimmingly _outside_ of conda.

Comment: But yes, make sure you have `pkg-config` to and `pkg-config --libs libcurl` returns what is expected -- `-lcurl` here on 17.10

Comment: So `which pkg-config` returns `/usr/bin/pkg-config` and `pkg-config --libs libcurl` returns `-lcurl` as expected...

Comment: Maybe `libcurl.pc`  is getting picked in `/usr/bin/pkg-config` instead of `/home/cpat/miniconda3/lib/pkgconfig/` ?

Answer (score 0):

Installed it outside of conda and everything worked perfectly.